# Limit number of images per product - Magento

Tags: image, magento, limit

Does anyone know how to Limit the number of images per product that can be uploaded to - Magento? Say I only want to allow 6 images per product.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function saveAction()
{
    /* START: Handle the max images per product */
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $images = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($data['product']['media_gallery']['images']);
    if($totalImages = count($images)) {
        $maxPhotoPerProduct = 5;
        if($totalImages > $maxPhotoPerProduct) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Max. number of images per product reached, extra images have been removed'));
        }
        $_allowedImages = array_slice($images, 0, $maxPhotoPerProduct);
        //Return the allowed images back to the $_POST
        $_POST['product']['media_gallery']['images'] = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($_allowedImages);
    }
    /* END: Handle the max images per product */
    //Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($_POST['product']['media_gallery']['images'])); exit;
    //Run standard saveAction()
    parent::saveAction();
}
```

Note that code above is from my Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController class located in the “app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php” file.

Meaning I overwrote the default “app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php” controller by using the syntax shown below in Mymodule config.xml file.

```
</config>
...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sintax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
...
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if this would apply to a multi seller store where products are added from the frontend?

Comment: I implemented the code but users can still add more than 6 images :(